# Simple code using a serial port in a multiprocessing environment not working

Tags: python, multiprocessing, serial-port

I am trying to write a multiprocessing python script on Windows which will read a rs232 serial port in one process and send the data back to the main process.

I narrowed down my problem to the the creation of the serial port connection (in the main process) and using accessing it (in another process).  The script consists of two files.  The first file (`test-main.py`) is the main process, the second file (`test-class.py`) contains a serial port class.

**test-main.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import serial
from test_class import test

def main():

    #RS232 Parameteres to open serial connection
    test_serial = serial.Serial(
        port ='COM9',\
        baudrate=9600,\
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=0.1)

    #create instance of test class
    test_instance=test()

    #creat a new thread which will measure speed and initiate relay
    test_instance = Process(target=test_instance.test_method, args=(test_serial,))
    test_instance.daemon = True
    test_instance.start()

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**test-class.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import serial

class test:

    def test_method (self,rs232_connection):
        #main loop
        while 1==1:
            print(rs232_connection)
```

The error I get is:

```
*C:\Users\User\Documents\BatterUp\Python>py test-main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-main.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "test-main.py", line 22, in main
    test_instance.start()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 89, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
ValueError: ctypes objects containing pointers cannot be pickled
C:\Users\User\Documents\BatterUp\Python>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied*
```

Comment: Seems like passing the opened serial port to another process is the problem.  You could try opening the port in the process.  You wouldn't want to use the port in two different processes anyway since there would be no way to enforce concurrency.

Comment: There is not global memory shared between processes. Even if you were able pass a `serial.Serial` instance to another process as an argument, it's highly likely that it doesn't support multiprocessing. It would be best to do all the serial port accessing in the other process and just send the results back to the main process.

Comment: Thanks!  Problem solved.  I included all the serial port initialization in to the test_method and it works.